# webpack-dev-server Disconnect and Trying to reconnect... spam

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I just finished an angular project I was working on, but i
noticed something in the console, which I'd love to hide if that's
possible just to keep everything tidy.

It's the [webpack-dev-server] module constantly disconnecting and trying to reconnect, and spamming my console log. Like this:

```
polyfills.js:1919 [webpack-dev-server] Live Reloading enabled.
polyfills.js:1919 [webpack-dev-server] Disconnected!
polyfills.js:1919 [webpack-dev-server] Trying to reconnect...
polyfills.js:1919 [webpack-dev-server] Live Reloading enabled.
polyfills.js:1919 [webpack-dev-server] Disconnected!
polyfills.js:1919 [webpack-dev-server] Trying to reconnect...
polyfills.js:1919 [webpack-dev-server] Live Reloading enabled.
polyfills.js:1919 [webpack-dev-server] Disconnected!
polyfills.js:1919 [webpack-dev-server] Trying to reconnect...
```

Is there a fix for this, or is this just the way it is for now until the application goes into production?

Comment: I have the same issue!!!

Comment: service worker package install in your app?

Comment: on an angular project, I had this problem in all browsers, regardless of extensions. Everything was solved when I turned off the antivirus.

Answer (score 3):

in my case, the issue is with my virus guard Kaspersky.after i exited it the issue is resolved

Comment: You can also disable scanning for the ports that webpack-dev-server uses. (in Network Settings, change scanning to "Monitor selected network ports only", then in the list of ports, disable the ones you're using)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and fixed mine by allowing `localhost` in Kasperskey Antivirus.

Under Security > Security Settings >Safe Browsing >Advanced Settings > Trusted URLs, then click +Add and type in `localhost`, save.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it with

`npx webpack serve --allowed-hosts all`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The console repeatedly showed the Web Pack Server messages "Disconnected!" and "Trying to reconnect...". But only when the application is running under Chrome. The message does not show up when the application is running under Edge.

I read a lot of threads, but unfortunately nothing helped. Until I realized that my Chrome browser was outdated. After a quick update, the web pack server messages disappeared. Maybe someone else is facing the same issue.

Comment: The same for me. But for me google Chrome update is not working.

Comment: Same here, exactly as described, updated and it started working again... Thanks!