# webpack-dev-server in looping when I try to render an Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 14.1.0, I was making a personal project when my project starts to slow render.
When I saw de console at chrome, it was trying to looping render with the follow message:

> [webpack-dev-server] Live Reloading enabled. index.js:551

> [webpack-dev-server] Disconnected! index.js:551 [webpack-dev-server]

> Trying to reconnect...

I tryied find similar issues, but nothing, so I don't know exactly what causes this issue because when it starts run I was styling with CSS.

I checked out my **webpack-dev-server** version:

```
{ "webpack-dev-server": "4.9.3" }

  "peerDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.30.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0"
  }
  "bin": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "bin/webpack-dev-server.js"
  },
```

Someone already have something like that using Angular and knows how to solve it?

Edit: I the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144144/webpack-dev-server-disconnect-and-trying-to-reconnect-spam) at stack over flow and have no answers yet.

I finded in Angular documentation the ng build CLI command where compiles an Angular application or library into an output directory named dist/ at the given output path. So I triend but nothing yeat.

I realized that the error occurs when the app build with the chrome console open, when I close, the apps build normaly.

Using the **ng serve** and **ng build --watch --configuration development** command and now everything is working well. So I didn't uderstand yet the reason.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, have you managed to figure out the reason?

Comment: So after a day spent on research I noticed that I left the throttling on "Slow 3G" in my network tab. I switched it to "No throttling" and it resolved the problem.
Previously I never had any problem with this setting...
Also, this explains why the issue disappeared when I closed the console.

Comment: @VégerLóránd is correct , thanks I just changed the throttle now its fine

Comment: on an angular project, I had this problem in all browsers, regardless of extensions. Everything was solved when I turned off the antivirus.